# Using getAttribute to change a cell's background color

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm attempting to loop through the cells of a table using getAttribute for a cell with a blue background, then changing it to a yellow background. I know CSS can easily accomplish this task, however I want to understand using JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 3
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:blue">
      Cell 4
    </td>
</tr>
</table>



var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for(i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  if(cells[i].getAttribute('backgroundColor') == true) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
}
```

Console log isn't returning any errors. Any thoughts guys?

Thank you!

Comment: background color is not an attribute of the tag. so it returns null. that's why you dont get an error

Comment: You don't need to query the attribute. You only need to see if the cell currently has a blue background. Change your `if` to be: `if(cells[i].style.backgroundColor === "blue")...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `background` property isn't a DOM attribute, it's a **style** attribute.

**Note**: If you refer to the specified `td` element, use `cells[i]` instead, because `this` keyword in this particular case will **not** refer to the actually iterated element, but to the **window** object.

```js
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  if (cells[i].style.background == 'blue') {
    cells[i].style.background = "yellow";
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 3
    </td>
    <td style="background:blue">
      Cell 4
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**In case** that you would like to refer to the DOM attribute, you could apply following code:

```
if (cells[i].getAttribute('style') == 'background:blue') {
   cells[i].style.background = "yellow";
}
```

Comment: `getAttribute` is redundant here. Just use `cells[i].style.backgroundColor == "blue"`

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is pointless I know but I've added it **just in case** if OP really would like to use the `style` attrubute... (: